# Расскажите,пожалуйста,про составные союзы.От чего зависит постановка запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

Буду рад и признателен :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сайте Грамота.ру в Справочнике по пунктуации (Приложение 3. Составные союзы) говорится буквально следующее:

Пунктуационная трудность заключается в том, что такие союзы могут целиком входить в придаточную часть (в этом случае части союза не разделяются запятой) или же расчленяться (в этом случае запятая ставится перед второй частью союза, а первая включается в состав главной части сложноподчиненного предложения как соотносительное слово).

**Составной подчинительный союз расчленяется и запятая ставится между частями союза**, если выполняется хотя бы одно из следующих условий:

- перед составным союзом имеется отрицание «не»: *Она любила Ричардсона // Не потому, чтобы прочла, // Не потому, чтоб Грандисона // Она Ловласу предпочла…* А. Пушкин, Евгений Онегин. *Мне хочется назвать тебя женой // Не для того, чтоб всем сказать об этом, // Не потому, что ты давно со мной, // По всем досужим сплетням и приметам.* К. Симонов, Мне хочется назвать тебя женой…
- перед составным союзом есть усилительные, ограничительные и другие частицы, вводные слова, наречия: *Этюд казался ей ничтожным, и написала она его только затем, чтобы иметь лишний предлог сходить к художнику.* А. Чехов, Попрыгунья. *А сердце бьется лишь для того, чтобы волос становился все длиннее и краше.* Ю. Коваль, Недопесок. *В том селе был у одного козака, прозвищем Коржа, работник, которого люди звали Петром Безродным; может, оттого, что никто не помнил ни отца его, ни матери.* Н. Гоголь, Вечер накануне Ивана Купала.
- первая часть составного союза входит в ряд однородных членов предложения или параллельных конструкций: *Ромашов же краснел до настоящих слез от своего бессилия и растерянности, и от боли за оскорбленную Шурочку, и оттого, что ему сквозь оглушительные звуки кадрили не удавалось вставить ни одного слова.* А. Куприн, Поединок. 
  Автор желает подчеркнуть, что на первую часть составного союза падает логическое ударение: *Мужики тихи, робки и вежливы оттого, что у каждого для весу в кудели по камню…* М. Пришвин, Мирская чаша. *Я спросил у отца, что значит «особенный вечер». Отец объяснил мне, что этот вечер называется так потому, что он не похож на все остальные.* К. Паустовский, Сказочник.

В том случае, если составной союз целиком входит в придаточную часть, знаки препинания ставятся следующим образом:

А) Если придаточная часть предложения следует за главной – запятая ставится только перед союзом.

*[Калугин] рысцой ехал на бастион, с тем чтобы по приказанию генерала передать туда некоторые приказания.* Л. Толстой, Севастополь в мае. *Мы принялись бегать по закрайку самого берега, и все выходило отлично, несмотря на то что кое-где лед ломался и выступала вода.* Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Дурной товарищ.

Б) Если придаточная часть находится внутри главной – запятые ставятся перед союзом и после всего придаточного предложения.

*Он, несмотря на то что был в упоительном чаду пива и вина, чувствовал, что несколько неприлично в таком виде и при таком действии находиться в присутствии постороннего свидетеля.* Н. Гоголь, Невский проспект. *Все возы, потому что на них лежали большие тюки с шерстью, казались очень высокими и пухлыми.* А. Чехов, Степь. *Художник, оттого что выпил два стакана портеру, как-то вдруг опьянел и неестественно оживился.* А. Чехов, Припадок.

В) Если придаточная часть предшествует главной – запятая ставится только после всего придаточного предложения.

*С тех пор как вечный судия // Мне дал всеведанье пророка, // В очах людей читаю я // Страницы злобы и порока.* М. Лермонтов, Пророк. *Вместо того чтобы становиться толпой против толпы, люди расходятся врозь, нападают поодиночке.* Л. Толстой, Война и мир. *В случае если Исполнитель не выполнил своих обязательств в сроки, указанные в настоящем Договоре, Заказчик вправе расторгнуть Договор.*

**Некоторые закономерности**

Анализ примеров из художественной литературы позволяет разделить составные подчинительные союзы на четыре группы (в зависимости от особенностей пунктуационного оформления) и выявить следующие закономерности:

1. Составные подчинительные союзы ввиду того что; вместо того чтобы; в случае если / когда; в то время как; для того чтобы; до того как; мало того что; на случай если; несмотря на то что; оттого что; перед тем как; подобно тому как; по мере того как; после того как; потому что; прежде чем; при том что; с тем чтобы; с тех пор как могут целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но могут и расчленяться – в зависимости от приведенных выше условий. При этом следует отметить, что союзы ввиду того что, до того как, на случай если чаще расчленяются, союз прежде чем чаще не расчленяется, а перед союзом несмотря на то что запятая сохраняется и в случае его расчленения (это обусловлено тем, что союз образован при участии отглагольного предлога).
2. Составные подчинительные союзы благодаря тому, что; во имя того, чтобы; в отношении того, что; вплоть до того, что; в связи с тем, что; в силу того, что; вследствие того, что; в сравнении с тем, что; до тех пор, пока; за счёт того, что; затем, чтобы / чтоб; за то, что; из-за того, что; на основании того, что; насчёт того, что; на том основании, что; независимо от того, что; под видом того, что; под предлогом того, что; под тем предлогом, что; по поводу того, что; по причине того, что; по той причине, что; при всём том, что; при условии, что / если;  ради того, чтобы; раньше, чем; с той целью, чтобы расчленяются (т. е. запятая ставится между частями союза). При этом, если придаточная часть присоединяется союзами вплоть до того, что; вследствие того, что; на основании того, что; на том основании, что; независимо от того, что, возможна постановка запятой не только между частями союза, но и перед союзом (если он расположен не в начале предложения).
3. Составные подчинительные союзы исходя из того, что; невзирая на то, что; смотря по тому, что; судя по тому, что (образованные при участии отглагольных предлогов), а также союзы вопреки тому, что; за исключением того, что; кроме того, что; помимо того, что расчленяются, при этом запятая ставится не только между частями союза, но и перед союзом (если он расположен не в начале предложения).
4. Составные подчинительные союзы как если бы; меж / между тем как; потому как; словно как; так что (в значении следствия); тем более что; тогда как не расчленяются (т. е. запятая между частями союза не ставится).